# What is opencsv.jar? Why do we use in jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I just want to know what is `opencsv.jar` and why do we use it in `jmeter`. I tried to find more about it on the internet but could not find a proper answer. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: `opencsv` is used to read/write from comma-separated text files amd I guess to reason it's used in `jmeter` is because that tool can export to csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware JMeter doesn't use opencsv.jar anywhere.

[CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) is used for test parametrization in order to make test data-driven by loading test data from external CSV files

[CSVSaveService](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/save/CSVSaveService.java) is used to dump test results into a CSV file.

Both of them rely on [Apache JMeter JOrphan library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/jorphan)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ - it's a library for processing csv files.